# How can I have a nested list on the left side of its wrapper without breaking the nesting?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to update my personal website with a new Jekyll theme, and I have some nested lists that I'd like to keep in my content. The CSS from the theme sets the `padding-left` value for `<ul>` to 0 and it ends up breaking the nesting of my list. How can I keep the list padded 0 to the left without breaking the nesting? I'd like keep the list style consistent throughout the site.

Markdown source:

```markdown
+ item
  + nested item
+ item 2
  + nested item 2
```

HTML Output:

```html
<ul>
  <li>item
    <ul>
      <li>nested item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item 2
    <ul>
      <li>nested item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Actual Output:

- item
- nested item
- item 2
- nested item 2

Intended Output:

- item

  - nested item
- item 2

  - nested item 2

Comment: Just apply padding again for the non-top-level ULs ...?

Comment: While it does work (using `padding-left: revert;`, I'd rather not write out the HTML for the list (lots of nested `ul` and `li` elements), especially if I decide to add more complexity to the list. I'd like a solution that I can maybe add to the theme's CSS.

**EDIT:** adding the above CSS property to `ul` children of `li` using the child selector `li > ul` seemed to work.